# React router is unmounting and remounting child component on every update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have create a component which is a wrapper around a form component :

```
class RestaurantEdit extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { waitingForRequest: false }
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    const { currentRequestState } = this.props
    const { waitingForRequest } = this.state
    if (
      waitingForRequest &&
      prevProps.currentRequestState === requestStates.PENDING &&
      currentRequestState === requestStates.SUCCESS
    ) {
      this.props.history.goBack()
      this.setState({ waitingForRequest: false })
    }
  }

  handleSubmit = (restaurantInfos, restaurantId) => {
    const { editRestaurant } = this.props
    const { password, ...dataWithoutPassword } = restaurantInfos
    this.setState({ waitingForRequest: true })
    if (password === '') {
      editRestaurant(restaurantId, dataWithoutPassword)
    } else {
      editRestaurant(restaurantId, restaurantInfos)
    }
  }

  handleCancel = () => {
    this.props.history.goBack()
  }

  render() {
    const { id, data = {} } = this.props
    const { password, ...dataWithoutPassword } = data
    return (
      <RestaurantForm
        id={id}
        data={dataWithoutPassword}
        onCancel={this.handleCancel}
        onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
        isPasswordRequired={false}
      />
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  currentRequestState: restaurantSelectors.getRequestState(state)
})

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  editRestaurant: (restaurantId, restaurantInfos) => {
    dispatch(editRestaurantRequested(restaurantId, restaurantInfos))
  }
})

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(RestaurantEdit)
```

this component is mounted in its parent in a React router switch :

```
    <Switch>
      <Route
        path="/restaurants/new"
        exact
        component={props => (
          <RestaurantCreate onSuccess={this.handleSuccess} {...props} />
        )}
      />
      <Route
        path="/restaurants/edit"
        component={props => {
          const id = props.location.search.split('=')[1]
          const data = currentCityRestaurants.find(resto => resto.id === id)
          return <RestaurantEdit id={id} data={data} {...props} />
        }}
      >
      </Route>
      <Route
        path="/restaurants"
        exact
        component={/* otherComponent */}
      />
    </Switch>
```

My big issue here is that when I try to dispatch an action (for example `editRestaurant`, which is given to `RestaurantEdit` as props by the mapDispatchToProps), the store is getting updated, and that will make the component unmount and remount.

This unmounting will prevent `this.setState({ waitingForRequest: true })` in the `componentDidUpdate` to complete, and `waitingForRequest` will always be false

I have noticed that if I pass the component as a direct child of `Route` the unmounting/remounting will not happen:

```
      <Route
        path="/restaurants/edit"
        exact
      >
        <RestaurantEdit …… />
      </Route>
```

But I cannot use this solution as I need to access the `location` and `history` provided by the `Route` component.

So is there a way to prevent all this unmounting/remounting with React router, when I’m passing the component as the `component` prop to `Route` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want some added functionality when rendering an element within a route you need to use the `render` keyword in place of `component`

In your example

```
<Route
    path="/restaurants/edit"
    component={props => {
      const id = props.location.search.split('=')[1]
      const data = currentCityRestaurants.find(resto => resto.id === id)
      return <RestaurantEdit id={id} data={data} {...props} />
    }}
  >
```

Change the component keyword to render and use a function to return the modified component

```
<Route
    path="/restaurants/edit"
    render={ props => {
      const id = props.location.search.split('=')[1]
      const data = currentCityRestaurants.find(resto => resto.id === id)
      return (<RestaurantEdit id={id} data={data} {...props} />)
    }}
  >
```

> This allows for convenient inline rendering and wrapping without the undesired remounting explained above

https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/render-func

Answer (score 1):

This is what happens when you use anonymous functions in your render cycle. React doesn't know that the output of your anonymous function is the same as it was last render, which is why the component unmounts and remounts.

With that being said, you don't need to use the render prop function to get access to the Route props. They're passed as props to your component already.

```
<Route
  path="/restaurants/edit"
  component={RestaurantEdit}
/>
```

```
const RestaurantEdit = (props) => {
  console.log(props.location, props.history)

  return ...
}
```

Comment: The thing is that I need to pass other props as well, `id` and `data`, not just location and history